# Enhanced Ecommerce - Magento product clicks

Tags: magento, google-analytics

Hi I have enabled enhanced ecommerce on GA and using select_content to track product clicks.

select_content is showing in real time but nothing shows up when I click into it.

Here is my code

```
<?php 
    $sku ="";
    $productname ="";
    $productcategory ="";

    $current_product = Mage::registry('current_product');
    $_category_detail=Mage::registry('current_category');

    if($current_product) {
        $sku = $current_product->getSku();
        $productname = $current_product->getName();
        $productcategory = $_category_detail->getName();;
    }

?>

<script>

    gtag('event', 'select_content', {
      "content_type": "product",
      "items": [
        {
          "id": "<?php echo $sku; ?>",
          "name": "<?php echo $productname; ?>",
          "list_name": "Search Results",
          "category": "<?php echo $productcategory; ?>"
        }
      ]
    });

</script>
```

Event category is showing as engagement and event action as select_content. When I click into engagement - the action is select_content and event label is product. There isn't a list of products.

Can someone help please?

Comment: Are you looking for product details in the realtime reports, or are you checking them at Conversion / Ecommerce reports?

Comment: both to be honest! not seeing results anywhere. Where in Ecommerce reports should the data show? Product Performance?

Comment: Actually, you won't see the ecommerce data in realtime reports. You'll only see the event details, if the hit has reached Google Analytics. Enhanced ecommerce data can be seen at Conversions / Ecommerce / Product performance or Product list performance. Can you verify in your browser, whether the product data is sent with the event? After the event being triggered, look at latest network call to https://www.google-analytics.com/collect address, and check, if e.g. "pa" parameter is set to "click".

Comment: I have checked view source and the above array is populated with the product details. I've had a look at the network tab - found google-analytics.com/collect and pa is set to click. So I'm on the right track? Do I just need to wait for Conversion / Ecommerce to populate? how long does this usually take?

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing further details. Can you maybe share a screenshot of all hit parameters from the network tab? (Without property ID and any sensitive data.) Free version of Analytics has 48 hours SLA for processing your data, although it's usually updated much faster. It's a good sign, that the product action was populated.